# Unable to deploy AWS Lambda C# blank function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Unable to deploy AWS Lambda C# blank function

I believe that the following line is failing:

```
dotnet lambda package
```

I am getting started with AWS and Lambda. My platform is a bash shell on Windows 10. I have installed AWS CLI v2, and .NET Core v3.1, both appear to be installed ok:

```
$ aws --version
aws-cli/2.1.13 Python/3.7.9 Windows/10 exe/AMD64 prompt/off

$ dotnet --version
3.1.404
```

I am trying to walk through the blank function sample:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/samples-blank.html

Instructions for C#:
https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-lambda-developer-guide/blob/main/sample-apps/blank-csharp/README.md

Per the instructions, I added the following to my .aws/config file:

```
cli_binary_format = raw-in-base64-out
```

The first step was successful, the S3 bucket was created:

```
$ ./1-create-bucket.sh
make_bucket: lambda-artifacts-1234567890123456

$ aws s3 ls
2020-12-30 14:30:25 lambda-artifacts-1234567890123456
```

But the second step, deployment, fails:

```
$ ./2-deploy.sh
Could not execute because the specified command or file was not found.
Possible reasons for this include:
* You misspelled a built-in dotnet command.
* You intended to execute a .NET Core program, but dotnet-lambda does not exist.
* You intended to run a global tool, but a dotnet-prefixed executable with this name could not be found on the PATH.
```

The contents of that shell script are:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -eo pipefail
ARTIFACT_BUCKET=$(cat bucket-name.txt)
cd src/blank-csharp
dotnet lambda package
cd ../../
aws cloudformation package --template-file template.yml --s3-bucket $ARTIFACT_BUCKET --output-template-file out.yml
aws cloudformation deploy --template-file out.yml --stack-name blank-csharp --capabilities CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM
```

I assume that the error is reported by line 5 invoking dotnet, since the error report refers to dotnet.

I tried to install the Lambda tools in dotnet, but that failed:

```
$ dotnet tool install -g Amazon.Lambda.Tools
error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'amazon.lambda.tools (>= 0.0.0)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1'.
error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'amazon.lambda.tools (>= 0.0.0)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1/any'.
The tool package could not be restored.
Tool 'amazon.lambda.tools' failed to install. This failure may have been caused by:
You are attempting to install a preview release and did not use the --version option to specify the version.
A package by this name was found, but it was not a .NET Core tool.
The required NuGet feed cannot be accessed, perhaps because of an Internet connection problem.
You mistyped the name of the tool.
For more reasons, including package naming enforcement, visit https://aka.ms/failure-installing-tool
```

Similar result when trying to install the Lambda templates:

```
$ dotnet new -i Amazon.Lambda.Templates
Determining projects to restore...
C:\Users\Me\.templateengine\dotnetcli\v3.1.404\scratch\restore.csproj : error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'Amazon.Lambda.Templates (>= 0.0.0)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0'.
Failed to restore C:\Users\Me\.templateengine\dotnetcli\v3.1.404\scratch\restore.csproj (in 179 ms).
```

I tried uninstalling .NET Core SDK v3.1 and repeating with .NET Core SDK v2.1, and also with .NET SDK 5.0, same results. I tried disabling anti-virus, no effect.

Should I have installed the AWS SDK? I did try, but yet more failure. I downloaded
awssdk.lambda.3.5.6.8.nupkg
from
https://www.nuget.org/packages/AWSSDK.Lambda/
and from the directory containing this nupkg file:

```
$ dotnet add package AWSSDK.Lambda
Could not find any project in 'C:\AwsSdkLambda\'.
```

I'd very much appreciate any suggestions.

Thanks,
Henry

Comment: Can you try install Amazon Lambda Tools with this command `dotnet tool install --global Amazon.Lambda.Tools --version 5.0.0`?

Comment: Thanks Hossam, but same result:
$ dotnet tool install --global Amazon.Lambda.Tools --version 5.0.0
error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'amazon.lambda.tools (>= 5.0.0)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1'.
etc.

Comment: I have installed the same `dotnet SDK` version `3.1.404` as you and successfully installed `Amazon.Lambda.Tools` package. Are you accessing from a network behind a proxy or a firewall that blocks traffic to `Nuget.org`?

Comment: No proxy, and no firewall other than Windows firewall on my PC. My web browser can visit www.nuget.org, so I don't think it's being blocked. I can't ping nuget.org, but they probably haven't enabled ping.

Comment: I manually downloaded the package from `https://www.nuget.org/packages/Amazon.Lambda.Tools/5.0.0`. The downloaded package filename is `amazon.lambda.tools.5.0.0.nupkg`. I then tried to install this local copy of the package, but it failed: `$ dotnet tool install -g Amazon.Lambda.Tools --add-source ./amazon.lambda.tools.5.0.0.nupkg 
  C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.404\NuGet.targets(128,5): error : The local source 'C:\Users\Me\Desktop\amazon.lambda.tools.5.0.0.nupkg' doesn't exist. (C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Temp\g23ky0jg.io4\restore.csproj)
The tool package could not be restored.`